# Different results acquired in Gridsearch tuning

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below code represents bagging algorithm parameters tuning using grid search method. At each execution of the code i got a different results for the best_parameters even though i have setted the seed and the random_state of each model decision tree and the bagging ensemble. It there ay advice?

```
# Bagged Decision Trees for Classification
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from random import seed
seed=1
#X=datascaled.iloc[:,0:71]
#Selected_features=['Event','AVK','Beta blockers','proton pump inhibitor','Previous stroke','CYP2C19*17','Clopidogrel active metabolite','Obesity']
Selected_features=['Event time','CYP2C19*17','Clopidogrel active metabolite', 'proton pump inhibitor', 'DOSE BB','Previous stroke', 'Obesity','AVK']
X=datascaled[Selected_features]
Y=datascaled['Cardio1']
# Split the dataset in two equal parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =model_selection.train_test_split(
    X,Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)
param_grid = {
    'base_estimator__max_depth' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'max_samples' : [0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5], 'max_features' : [0.5, 1, 2],
    'n_estimators' : [10,20,50, 100, 150, 200], #here you must add 'random_state':[123], 'n_jobs':[-1]



}

clf = GridSearchCV(BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                                     n_estimators = 50, max_features = 0.5),
                   param_grid,cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
#The best hyper parameters set
print("Best Hyper Parameters:\n",clf.best_params_)
prediction=clf.predict(X_test)
#importing the metrics module
from sklearn import metrics
#evaluation(Accuracy)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(prediction,y_test))
#evaluation(Confusion Metrix)
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split,StratifiedShuffleSplit,cross_val_score
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from time import *
from sklearn import metrics
n_folds=10
DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features=2, class_weight = "balanced",max_depth=4 ,random_state=seed)
#model=BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = DTC,random_state = 11, n_estimators= 50)
model=BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = DTC, max_samples= 0.5, n_estimators= 150)
cv = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(Y, n_folds=n_folds, random_state=42)
t0 = time()
y_pred = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(model, X=X, y=Y, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv)
t = time() - t0
print("=" * 52)
print("time cost: {}".format(t))
print()
print("confusion matrix\n", metrics.confusion_matrix(Y, y_pred))
print()
print("\t\taccuracy: {}".format(metrics.accuracy_score(Y, y_pred)))
print("\t\troc_auc_score: {}".format(metrics.roc_auc_score(Y, y_pred)))

print(metrics.classification_report(Y, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you are either having
1. Insifficient data/opportunity to arrive a convergence 
2. Model is largely underfitting, and each run is a variation

Comment: Nope i don't think that the problem related to the underfiting of  the model While i have already tested the model on different datasets and the problem remains i think there is an issue with my code i shared it to check it more

Comment: i gonna try it now do you have a seed suggestion?

Comment: by the way i found 42 and 123 the most widely used in bagging context

Comment: @RawiaSammout : Did you find the problem/solution for your above query ?

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve the issue by adding `random_state=123` in the grid and `n_jobs=-1`. I did a correction of the code above, I will mention it in a comment above.